# Set cookie with two different values

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm using jquery.cookie to set a cookie inside a modal where users sign up for a newsletter.

I have two scenarios for the cookie
1) Modal shows and user can check a checkbox "do not show again". Cookie needs to be set to 7 days. Or user clicks a ordinary "close / X " button

2) User fill in form and complete the signup process. When clicking a button "Finished" cookie needs to be set to 365 days.

I don't want to set a cookie on form submit since people can still abandon the form.

**I managed to get the checkbox cookie working but not the button cookie. Both need to check first if cookie is present and if not set the cookie depending on which action is taken.**

What am I doing wrong?

So what I have is this:

```
//The checkbox
<div class='modal-footer'>
 <div class="checkbox pull-right">
   <label for="modal-checkbox">dont show again</label>
   <input class='modal-check' id="modal-checkbox" name='modal-check' type="checkbox">
 </div>
</div>

//The button
<div class='modal-footer'>
 <button type="submit" id="success--btn "class="btn btn-custom-2 btn-block" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Finished!</button>          
</div>
```

Script

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    var my_cookie = $.cookie($('.modal-check').attr('name'));
    if (my_cookie && my_cookie == "true") {
      $(this).prop('checked', my_cookie);
    }
    else{
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('#newsletter').modal('show');
      }, secs);
    }
    $(".modal-check").change(function() {
      $.cookie($(this).attr("name"), $(this).prop('checked'), {
        path: '/',
        expires: 7
      });
    });
    $("#succes--btn").on("click", function () {
      $.cookie('my_cookie', '1234', {
        path: '/',
        expires: 365
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it may be only copying issue but you have a space in button id and it is also possible that default bootstrap click event causes that yours event is not being called:

```
//The button
<div class='modal-footer'>
    <button type="submit" id="success--btn" class="btn btn-custom-2 btn-block" aria-label="Close">Finished!</button>          
</div>
```

JavaScript could be simplified. You can try it this way :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //keep it simple, I suppose the cookie name will not change after all
    var regNewsletterCookie = $.cookie('regNewsletter');
    if (!regNewsletterCookie) {
        //my_cookie undefined or my_cookie false ends here
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#newsletter').modal('show');
        }, secs);
    }

    $(".modal-check").change(function() {
        $.cookie('regNewsletter', $(this).prop('checked'), {
        path: '/',
        expires: 7
    });
    //And there is also a typo in you selector succesS--btn
    $("#success--btn").on("click", function () {
        $.cookie('regNewsletter', true, {
            path: '/',
            expires: 365
        });
        $('#YourModalId').modal('hide');
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok I see what you have done! Should `$.cookie('my_cookie', true, {` not be `$.cookie('regNewsletter', true, {`?? Or maybe `my_cookie` without the comma's??

Comment: yeah sorry, I corrected the code so it should be better readable now